# Blank screen on device after running kotlin app

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on a kotlin app that simply display a pop-up when buttons are pressed, but for some reason whenever i run the app all i get is a blank white screen. I've tried so many solutions online all to no avail.

Here's my Main Activity code:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import com.example.popup.R
import com.example.popup.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private var activityMainBinding: ActivityMainBinding? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.lay_custom_dialog)
        title = "POP UP"
        activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        // add the following three lines
        activityMainBinding?.btnShowDefaultDialog?.setOnClickListener {
            showDefaultDialog()
        }
    }
    
    override fun onDestroy() {
        activityMainBinding = null
        super.onDestroy()
    }
    
    private fun showDefaultDialog() {
        val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    
        alertDialog.apply {
            setIcon(R.drawable.ic_hello)
            setTitle("Hello")
            setMessage("I just wanted to greet you. I hope you are doing great!")
            setPositiveButton("Positive") { _, _ ->
                toast("clicked positive button")
            }
            setNegativeButton("Negative") { _, _ ->
                toast("clicked negative button")
            }
            setNeutralButton("Neutral") { _, _ ->
                toast("clicked neutral button")
            }
        }.create().show()
    }
    private fun toast(text: String) = Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    
    }
```

And here's the activity_main.xml file(the button views are displayed on the view pager, but not on the device when run)

```
\<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"\>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnShowDefaultDialog"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/show_dialog"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.912" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnShowCustomDialog"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/show_custom_dialog"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btnShowDefaultDialog"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.238"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.977" />
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's the Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Popup"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You didn't post your manifest in the question, you just repeated the layout XML file.

Comment: Your code displays fine for me using the second version of the layout you posted (without the errors), so have a look in your logs to see if there's any info about something going wrong. Also whatever `R.layout.lay_custom_dialog` is, make sure there's nothing in there causing problems. You don't need to call `setContentView(R.layout.lay_custom_dialog)` anyway (you're setting a different layout two lines later) but that's the only place I can think there's a problem

Comment: Thanks for the observation about the manifest, it has been corrected. On the other hand, the code runs just fine without any errors in the log.

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreate()` you call

```
setContentView(R.layout.lay_custom_dialog)
```

however, you say that the layout file for your `Activity` is called `activity_main.xml`. You should be doing this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

Comment: oh, yes... thanks @David Wasser, i initially did that to verify if anything was wrong with my ```activity_main.xml``` layout file, by creating a new layout file(lay_custom_dialog). Either case it's still the same result